# How to use NSIS with Maven2 and continuous integration?

Tags: maven-2, continuous-integration, nsis

I want to include an installer created by NSIS into a Java project organized with Maven2.  How can I incorporate this so that the installer is automatically built each time I use maven to create a distribution?  I've tried the following:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

The only way I could include the plugin was by pulling down a copy of the source in svn and building my own snapshot of the codehaus plugin code.  Now it tells me I need to enter the location of makensis.  Problem being, the continuous integration server is running on linux.  Am I SOL?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352351/automating-nsis-script-build-using-maven2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

makensis (The NSIS compiler) compiles and runs on POSIX platforms, see the [NSIS documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixG.html#G.3) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can also compile makensis yourself on Linux:
http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/How-to-Install-the-Nullsoft-Installer-NSIS-on-Linux-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The other answer helped, but as additional information for anyone who may read this-- there are precompiled versions of makensis available for linux.  The package I installed is mingw32-nsis, and for fedora/redhat/centos, you can do: `yum install nsis`.

http://hany.sk/~hany/RPM/mingw32-nsis.html