# Using the bundled Maven NSIS Plug-in with maven 3.x

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-3, nsis

I've got an NSIS script for generating an installer for my Java app - I'd like to automate this using Maven.

Rather than using the plugin at Mojo Project, http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/, is it possible to use the bundled plugin http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/nsis/ in Maven 3.x or is this just for Maven 1.x?

I'm aware of how to use the Mojo Project plugin, thanks to this question, [Automating NSIS script build using maven2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352351/automating-nsis-script-build-using-maven2/10595214) , I just want to make sure I'm selecting the correct, support plugin for my version of Maven.

Comment: Hi. Did you found the plugin for maven 3.x? Or you're using the one from 1.x?

Comment: I stuck with http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/nsis-maven-plugin/1.0-alpha-1